# Canvas Constellation Interactive Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Boa tarde,

Tenho um código de um canvas constellation que faz interação com o **mouseover** puxando as ligações das estrelas para próximo ao mouse, e gostaria de fazer no mobile a mesma coisa, *para o clique ele funciona*, mas gostaria que ele também "sentisse" e seguisse o toque para fazer o scroll (o deslizar de dedo na tela) e seguisse onde o dedo está colocado.

Código do handler:

```
this.handlers = {
        window: {
            mousemove: function(e){
                config.position.x = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
                config.position.y = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
            },
            touchmove: function(e){
                config.position.x = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
                config.position.y = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
            },
            resize: function () {
                window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.rAF);
            }
        }
    };
```

Tentei utilizar o meio de pegar ligação diferente mas também não rolou?

Teste no mobile
https://codepen.io/pcordista/pen/PoYNxpQ?editors=1010

Alguém me da uma ajuda?